# Why can't I declare a parameterized static class variable?

Tags: java, generics, static

Trying to create a static field with a generic type doesn't compile:

```
class MyClass {

    public static Function<Z, Z> blargh = new Function<Z, Z>() {
        public Z apply(Z a) {
            return a;
        }
    };
}
```

Eclipse says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Z cannot be resolved to a type
    - Z cannot be resolved to a type
    - Z cannot be resolved to a type
    - Z cannot be resolved to a type
    - The type new Function<Z,Z>(){} must implement the inherited 
     abstract method Function<Z,Z>.apply(Z)
```

but replacing all the `Z`s with a concrete type works just fine:

```
static Function<Integer, Integer> blargh = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(Integer a) {
        return a;
    }
};
```

What's going on here?

---

Context:

1. I was originally trying to figure out why [this code](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/Bottom.java) uses a method instead of a field:

   ```
   public static <T extends Throwable> F<T, String> eMessage() {
     return new F<T, String>() {
       public String f(final Throwable t) {
         return t.getMessage();
       }
     };
   }
   ```

   Maybe it's to overcome this restriction?
2. the `Function` type is from Google's guava library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: Now I see the problem better.

I think that firstly you would have to declare the type as a class parameter:

```
class MyClass<Z> {
```

to get visibility, but now the reason you can't use it like that is because the static member should be shared among all the instances of the class. But since you could create instances with different type parameters, the static member depending on a particular type would not make sense.

Comment: @Matt Fenwick: Can you show the code around the static member? Specifically the class where you declared it?

Answer (score 3):

You can only use class-level generics on member fields. For example:

```
public class MyClass<Z> {
    private Function<Z, Z> function;
    // ...
}
```

is correct. Declaring this `static` instead will break. Why?

Think about `ArrayList`. Its class declaration is something like:

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>, ... {
    // ...
}
```

`E` has no context in a static sense, because static variables belong to all instances of `ArrayList`, but `E` can be different for each `ArrayList` instance:

```
// Here's one ArrayList with E as String
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
// And another with E as Boolean
List<Boolean> bools = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

So because `E` can change from instance to instance, it doesn't make sense to have an `E` variable at the `static` level.

Now you *can* declare `static` methods with generics, but in a totally different way. For example, `Collections.sort` could have a declaration like this:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<? extends T> list, Comparator<T> comparator)
```

Notice that `T` is declared as part of the method before the return type. This is defining the context of `T` within the method, and `T` can differ from call to call.

Post-edit remark: in your case, you don't have `Z` declared anywhere, so you won't be able to use it anyway. See my declaration above for `MyClass`. Notice how I used `<Z>` directly on the class? That means that `Z` will be some arbitrary type.

In the case of what you were trying to figure out, you should look at `Function` as a generic way of representing a transformation. Let's dissect your posted method:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> F<T, String> eMessage() {
    return new F<T, String>() {
        public String f(final Throwable t) {
            return t.getMessage();
        }
    };
}
```

First, note that this is a method, not a static field like your OP, so it's legal to have generics here. Also, it's `static`, so any generics need to be declared before the return type. Here, they declare `<T extends Throwable>`, so `T` must be some kind of error or exception that extends `Throwable`. The return type is `F<T, String>`, which is a function that takes a `T` (a `Throwable`) and returns a `String`. The actual object declares an `f` method which does just that by calling `Throwable.getMessage`. Since the project is functionaljava, everything is based on the `F` class, so generics are everywhere.

Just remember:

1. Generics declared at the class level can only be used by non-static members and methods.
2. Generics declared at the method level are allowable, but don't refer to the class-level types, referring instead to types declared before the return type.
3. Generics declared at the static field level simply aren't allowed because they'll never have context for their concrete type.

Comment: It's worth noting that although in Java, an `GenericType<BaseClass>` and a `GenericType<DerivedClass>` are really *the same type*, not all object-oriented frameworks work that way.  In .net (and probably some other frameworks as well), every combination of generic type parameters that is used during program execution will generate a different generic type, with its own set of static variables.  Anyone who wishes to switch from one framework to the other should be aware of such distinctions.

Comment: @supercat Good point. Java's erasure is ultimately responsible for that caveat. Good to point out that other languages may have (and usually do have) different semantics because of the lack of erasure. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest answer might be that: although the JDK compiler is flexible in how it interprets generics, it is impossible to modify or specify the "Z" class given the semantics of your code.

In all use of generics, you must define a syntax which specifies the identity of the generic class that is being operated upon.  For example (As in the examples above).

1) Use a generic, parameterized utility function.  In this case, its obvious to the compiler because the specified class is sent as input the function.

2) Define the class itself as being generic, and non static.  This would then require that the user of the class declare it with the proper specified class parameter.

Specifically, for Function classes, you are clearly defining a constrained class : one which takes "Z" as input, and returns "Z" as output.  If you want to generify this, you might create a FunctionFactory class, which takes in, for example, a single instance of Z, and returns a type-specified function of type :

```
public static <Z> Function<Z,Z> functionFactory(final Z default){
                    return new Function<Z,Z>(){
                        @Override
                        public Z apply(Z input) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(input==null)
                                         return default;
                                    else 
                                         return input;
                        }
                    };
            }
```